# Are there circumstances where an Akka-based application can replace a Hadoop setup?

Tags: hadoop, akka

From reading about Akka and my own beginning uses of it, it seems to me that Akka could be used, and more simply, than a Hadoop setup for some applications. You wouldn't have HDFS for use, but you could write an application that would send out pieces of work to different "mappers" and have results sent to a "reducer", and it would be easier to set up than Hadoop in VMs or on hardware, fewer services to set up.
Is this reasonable or are the two technologies used for totally different things?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, totally reasonable.  We have built a large scale (1000+ workers) map-reduce system using Akka 2.0.  Akka 2.2+ is even better because you can use the [clustering](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-usage.html) and [remote deathwatch](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html) features instead of having to write that functionality yourself.

See [this post](http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2) to get a feel for how it might work.

Comment: Thanks, the post does a good job of explaining. I'll look into clustering as well.

Answer (score 0):

Akka cluster is currently marked experimental but the Akka team say it's more or less ready for prime time and people are using it in production. I would be very cautious about going this direction and you may instead want to consider hadoop or using zookeeper with akka and zmq or a message queue for horizontally scaling as well.